# Calculated field that will get the % total from a specific date to a year back

Tags: tableau-api

**DataTypes**

**AffectedDate**: Date & Time

**RecDate**: Date & Time

[image]

I have 2 Data Sources i am pulling my data from.

[image]

Above is the Data that is being pulled into this report. The **AffectedDate** comes from the Data source **Elliott_QtyOnHand2** and it controls how many years/months are displayed.

[image]

I have this calculated field and the amount that shows  up is controlled by the **RecDate**, which is in the **Elliott_IssueQty** data source.

Right now the Prev Amount Calculated field changes when i put the **RecDate** in the Filter area because **the RecDate dictates how much data is summed in the Sum(Amount) part of the Prev Amount calculated field**.

Right now i can put the RecDate in the filter area to show me the **sum(Amount)** in the **Prev Amount calculated field** of everything between a range of dates, but i need this to be done on the fly, as each field will be different.

For example if the **Affected Date** is Jan, 2017 we want the **Sum(Amount) in the Prev Amount Calculated field** to only sum from Jan, 2016 to Jan, 2017, **which again is calculated off of the RecDate**

Feb, 2017 would sum(amount) between Feb, 2016 - Feb, 2017 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated field and write below code:

```
[Order Date] >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())) AND 
[Order Date] < MAKEDATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))
```

Replace order date with date field in your database.

Place the calcualted field in filter shelf and then select `true`

**Edit--------------------------------------------------------------------**

Using filter doesn't help dynamic functionality of your requirement, instead you need to use parameter to achieve this:

Create a parameter `select date` and then select datatype as `date`, Here you can manually type values or select any database field using `list radio button` and display format should be `month year` from drop down.

Now crate a calculated field and write below code.

```
        [Order Date] >= MAKEDATE(YEAR([Parameter 1])-1,MONTH([Parameter 1]),1) 
AND 
[Order Date] < MAKEDATE(YEAR([Parameter 1]),MONTH([Parameter 1])+1,1)

    //Change order date to your **Rec Date**, if **Rec Date** is `date time` then convert t0 date format, else just replace the order date with **REc date**
```

Place the created calculated field on filter area and select `true`

Note: if you are using the datbase filed to populate the parameter values then if any new data additions to database you need to update the parameter manually or just follow method in [link](https://www.interworks.com/blog/daustin/2015/12/17/dynamic-parameters-tableau)

if you need I can share workbook, drop a comment if you have any queries

[image]

Comment: this does not work. MAKEDATE does not work with data sources as SQL Server. Also it is telling me i cannot compare int to string. Also, i am not trying to get data compared to TODAY, i want the data to be pulled from a specific time. So if the date field says 2015-01 then i want to get a sum of all the data from 2015-01 all the way back to 2014-01.

Comment: @Ezzy MAKEDATE is a function in tableau and I have tested against Excel connection and I was successful in getting the data. If you are getting error `Cannot compare to string` then you need to provide what exactly your date format in database (Give full details in question). If you are not comparing to today then you are not giving the exact details, Update your question with exact details will provide exact solution

Comment: @Ezzy i have updated with pictures. please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Ezzy got it but you didn't mention what is the datatype of the date field, Also if you can share the workbbok with dummy data will change and attach the same

Comment: i have updated with the data types. I am not sure how to update with sample data, as this data is coming from MSSQL?

Comment: i have not tried this yet, but i did try MAKEDATE and this function does not work on data being pulled form MSSQL.

Comment: can you explain to me the parameter? So the report will show all the data for 2014 - 2018 (Current Date) and each month will need to have that calculation Jan 18' will be Jan18 - Jan17 and Feb18' will be Feb18 - Feb17 and if the date field is March17' it will be March17 - March16

Comment: When you need the user interaction with user defined data then you go for parameter, In your case you are looking for custom filtering part where if you use Year(Date) as a filter then you won't be able to get one year previous data hence we use parameter and then manipulate the data as per requirement

Comment: @Ezzy MAKEDATE should work as I was able to successfully get the data, Can you post your code here?

Comment: So MAKEDATE only works on data extracts, not on live data. this needs t be a live connection.

Comment: so i need another way to do that as this needs to be a live connection.

Comment: I tested makedate on live connection... but it will work on all connections either live or extract

Comment: it says unkown function. based on the research i have done it does not work. I am using MSSQL and it is not recognizing this function.